# Timing a line of code accurately in a threaded application, C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the most accurate way of timing a thread or a line of code in C# assuming the application is multithreaded?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "timing a thread"?

To just time (in wall time) how long something takes, use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch. I don't believe there's anything to measure the processor time taken by a particular thread.  Of course, profilers will help you a lot, but they also affect the timing of the program they're examining, which makes things trickier.

Comment: The problem is we have got around 20 threads and want to know the processor tine taken by each thread.

Comment: Is there no way that you can isolate the threads to benchmark each individually? You could use a profiler to get an idea of what's taking a long time within your threads, but that *will* affect the overall performance. (More for the more accurate instrumentation measures, less for sampling.)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to accurately time operations in .NET, you want the [Stopwatch](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class (which wraps the Windows QueryPerformanceCounter API).  Check out this (Internet Archive) [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090409105700/http://lyon-smith.org/blogs/code-o-rama/archive/2007/07/17/timing-code-on-windows-with-the-rdtsc-instruction.aspx) for thread timing considerations.