# How to control threads which are writing in a single file; Cannot use locks

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am creating threads and each thread will do some task and write consumed time; which it takes to complete a task, in a single file. I cannot use locks because if a thread go into waiting state I cannot measure exact time the thread takes to complete the task.

Is there any solution that I can track the exact time taken by threads to complete the task. Task is to run a function having some time-consuming work.

Comment: What do you mean by "which it takes to complete a task, in a single file"? What do the threads do? Some work and then write into the file? Or the work is to write in the file? You can "serialize" the writes in a single thread.

Comment: The title says "...threads...file...locks"; the description says "...measure time taken..."; the tag is generic "multithreading". Please, consider editing the question.

Comment: See Jon Skeet's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252793/timing-a-line-of-code-accurately-in-a-threaded-application-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you measure code block (thread) execution time with multiple concurrent threads in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375068/how-do-you-measure-code-block-thread-execution-time-with-multiple-concurrent-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Ticks` property to get the most fine-grained level of detail. A tick is 100ns, so divide by 10 to get to microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to file asynchronously. In this case, your threads call another `Task` that will write to file and continue execution, and this another `Task` will wait for lock.

Another solution - you can use queue (MSMQ as example) to send logging message and writing to file will be from single thread on another end of queue.

Comment: Queuing is a good option but what about when two threads try to write in queue at same time?

Comment: MSMQ is a service. It is refuse another messages when working with first one. But first solution is simpler in deployment.